# Seeking example that use the J programming language JHS web server as a service

Tags: j

The J programming language includes an embedded web server called JHS. The binary download comes with (on the mac) an app called jhs.app, which is, I think, intended to run JHS. However, there is no indication of what port the app is running on, and nothing to really suggest how it might be used. In particular, while the documentation I've found (https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/JHS/Help) talks about popups and other UI objects, it is unclear it can be used as a service, by passing a J language expression in the body of an HTTP request, or how that request should be structured if it is possible. This is the use-case I'm interested in.

I know this kind of question often gets downvotes or closed as being vague, with a suggestion of RTFM, but afaics, the single page above is the only existing documentation and it doesn't provide the needed info.

For that reason, I'm looking for a simple example of its usage as as service or pointers to the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the install instructions for an install of J901 from the zip installer there are some steps that show how to use the 3 user front ends to the J engine. They are jconsole, Jqt, and JHS. Following those instructions might give you more of an overview of how to use J.

On the Mac, double click the jhs.app icon to start a terminal window that runs the JHS server. This window has some info. In particular it suggest you run a browser and browse to an indicated page that will connect to the server and provide a simple IDE to the J engine.

Comment: This seems like the right answer. Unfortunately, on my mac the JHS app doesn't work. There's some animation when the icon is clicked but no terminal is opened. I will assume the answer is correct, but that there is some issue with the app on my platform.

Comment: @L.Blanc Open your Security and Privacy settings and see if it notes “unregistered app JHS tried to launch”. If that or something like the shows up, it should give you the option to “open anyway?” after re-entering your credentials. Macs have gotten way more security conscious the last few releases. This applies to jconsole and other binaries as well. If that’s not it, I’m out of ideas.

Comment: @DanBron I checked and there is no such message. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @L.Blanc if you are running Catalina there is an issue with the zsh shell currently that I believe is being worked on. If so, try the manual steps of:
1. start jconsole
2.    load'~addons/ide/jhs/config/jhs.cfg'
3. browse to http://localhost:65001/jijx

Comment: @bob I am on catalina, so that's probably the issue.